# Authentication for Rails 2.3.8 using MongoDB and mongo_mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, mongodb, mongomapper

How will I do authentication using Rails 2.3.8 using MongoDB and
mongo_mapper?

Let me know your expert advise on this.

By the way, a Rails noob here :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise). [Example app](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example) (Rails 2.3) and [another](http://github.com/fortuity/rails3-mongoid-devise) (Rails 3.0).

[Shapado](http://gitorious.org/shapado) is an excellent application using MongoMapper, MongoDB and Rails 3. It's a clone of Stackoverflow (yes, this site!).

[Diaspora](http://github.com/diaspora/diaspora) uses MongoMapper, MongoDB and Rails 3.